# Failed to write my custom dictionary data into plist file

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, plist

I am trying to write data into my `plist` file, which was created in `Library/Caches` in my app's sandbox, with the following custom helper method:

```
-(void)saveStatusesToPlist:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data": array};

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [cachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filepath];
    NSLog(@"PATH: %@", plistPath);

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        BOOL isCreated = [manager createFileAtPath:plistPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
        NSLog(@"Result：%@", isCreated? @"Success": @"Failed");
    }
    BOOL flag = [dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Write result：%@", flag? @"Success": @"Failed");
}
```

Please notice that the parameter: `array` is an array of many `NSDictionary` objects converted from `JSON` data which was fetched from server side over network.

**UPDATE:**
I got my array like this:

```
NSArray *array = [result objectForKey:@"array"];
```

But the result was always failed.

So I doubted that issue was from the `array` which may contain invalid data. Then I tried hardcode the `array` to sth like `@[@"key1": @"value1", @"key2": @"value2", @"key3": @"value3"]`.

With the hardcoded data, the `flag` returns `YES` meaning it was saved.

So at least I can tell that my fetched data has some problem but I don't know where it is.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my dictionary data which is very large:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can paste one of my dictionary model instances here if necessary

Comment: It works perfect in my project… I tried to write my own json array…
Could you paste one of your models?

Comment: @Che my one dictionary is quite large which contains many objects, so I'm pasting the screen shots here...

Comment: Seems like issue is in Dictionary's size… I created array with 30 dictionaries with 40 items on each. And I can't write it…
BUT!!! ;)

You can make something like this

`NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];
    BOOL flag = [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    
    NSData* savedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSDictionary* unarchivedDict = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedData];`

In this case - everything works fine.

Comment: Cool, it worked and perfectly meets my requirement, thanks! You may answer this question and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like issue is in Dictionary's size… 
I created array with 30 dictionaries with 40 items on each. And I can't write it… 
BUT!!! ;) 
You can make something like this:

```
NSData* data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict]; 
BOOL flag = [data writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

NSData* savedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSDictionary* unarchivedDict = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:savedData];
```

In this case - everything works fine.